# Struts2 Spring Hibernate Application

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

hi i'm working on a project that integrate struts2,spring an hibernate together, so when i run the project i get this message:

> Grave: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de
>   l'application (application listener)
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4660)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source).

please i need a help.thank you so much.

Comment: Please be more specific. Looks like a missing dependence. Could you post your `web.xml`?

Comment: Are you trying to use JSF?

Answer (score -1):

Struts Hibernate Examples

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```